# opencv2/opencv.hpp file not found in .pch file

Tags: ios, opencv

I downloaded openCV from this link : https://github.com/itseez/opencv
I dragged and dropped the folder into the 'Frameworks' folder in my project and it appeared under 'Link Binary with Libraries' under Targets''Build Phases'. 
I set 'Always Search User Paths:' to 'YES'. 
I added these frameworks under Targets'Link Binary with Libraries: Accelerate, AssetsLibrary, AVFoundation , CoreGraphics , CoreImage , CoreMedia , CoreVideo , QuartzCore , UIKit , Foundation.
I created a .pch file and added these lines:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#import <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#endif
```

I added the .pch file name beside 'Prefix Header' in Project's Build Settings.

Yet the build failed on running and the error 'opencv2/opencv.hpp file not found' appeared under the .pch file heading.

Please help.

Comment: Which IDE you are using to build?

Comment: XCode. The issue is fixed anyway. Thanks.

Comment: @nitinkmp In that case, please post an answer detailing how you fixed it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue got fixed by adding the library libc++.tdb, setting 'Prefix Header' as the absolute path of the .pch file and 
setting "Compile Sources As" - Object-C++ in "Build Settings" under "Apple LLVM 7.0 compiler - Language".